# Tagging guidelines

Tags: discussion, tags

If a question presents an understanding, and specifically requests an alternative, should the question be tagged as relating to the provided understanding?  For example, should [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9371/do-gentiles-have-neshamot) be a [tanya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tanya) question?

Also, if a question suggests that a certain source may be a source for what they are seeking, is that source relevant to the question?  For example, should [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/693/any-primary-sources-that-all-jewish-males-should-lchatchila-stay-in-learning-fo) be a [nefesh-hachaim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nefesh-hachaim) question?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the answer to the first question is yes - if the other source is a necessary part of answering the question, even though the answer sought is specifically not that source, then the question is related to that source.  Someone interested in Tanya may be interested in seeing that question which asks for a different perspective than the Tanya.

Regarding the second question, I'm on the fence.  On the one hand, the question remains the same if you would take out the author's suggested location for an answer.  On the other hand, someone looking to answer questions about Nefesh HaChaim may be interested to find that question.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the first question should not be tagged [tanya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tanya). The question isn't *about* Tanya; it just mentions it. Questions should be tagged with what they are about, not what they contain. There's an MSO or MSE guide about this somewhere, but i can't find it right now.

I agree [with YEZ](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2060/5151) about the second question - undecided.

Comment: My general understanding has been that tagging is not meant to tell you what the question is about, but to make it more easily findable to someone looking for questions about that topic, and things that would be of interest to someone searching within that topic should be included.  That's why I thought it should be tagged with _tanya_.

Comment: It could be that the policy here is a little different than on SO.