# Should tags on a question include the presumed answer?

Tags: discussion, tags

[This](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/52669/revisions) question I tagged as [`aishes-chayil`](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aishes-chayil) because, although the questioner didn't know the tag when they asked, it seemed germain to the topic of the question and all related questions would be of relevance to this one.

Another user disagreed.

My subconscious motivation is well described [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2059/tagging-guidelines#comment8451_2211):

> ... tagging is not meant to tell you what the question is about, but to make it more easily findable to someone looking for questions about that topic ...

So which is the appropriate tagging policy, one that would have included the tag on this case or that would exclude it?

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, it should be possible for someone to ask a question which never needs to be edited because they did a great job asking. As such, you can only use the content of the question in determining its tags.

So, [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37104/759) should not be tagged [yirmeyahu](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yirmeyahu). If the OP had said "Where in Yirmeyahu can these words be found?" that would be a different story.

Comment: If you were asking a question you already knew the answer to, you would know to tag it that way, though.

Comment: @Yishai [If you know the answer you should still always ask as if you didn't.](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/307/759)